# What do I do if I can't type double underscore in Python shell and IDLE in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, python-3.x

When I try to type the attributes of a class with 1 single underscore between each word I get the following error:

```
>>> class Dog:
    def_init_(self,color,legs):
    File "<stdin>", line 2
        def_init_(self,color,legs):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried using 2 single underscores together between each word of the class attributes hoping that the 2 single underscores would merge together, but that didn't happen and that also produced a syntax error.

Is there a way to merge 2 single underscores in Python's shell or IDLE? I tried changing my keyboard settings from windows settings menu, but I ended in the language/region section where I found the languages for the keyboard and I still haven't found a way to change or check the individual keys in of the Keyboard languages I have selected.

Comment: You first indicate the problem is caused by a single underscore, later in your question body, you indicate you have a problem with 2 underscores.  You might want to improve your question and clarify it.

Comment: Try adding a space between `def` and `__init__`, perhaps? i.e. `def __init__(self,color,legs):` (with double underscores). Also, it looks as if you may not have the correct number of spaces before `def`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a space after def with double-underscore. 

`def __init__(self,color,legs):`